# If $M \otimes M \simeq M$ is there anything we can say about $M$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Over a commutative (and unital) ring, if $M \otimes M \simeq M$ can we say anything about $M$?

If we base change to a point, ie tensor with a map from the ring into a field, then $M$ becomes a vector space and we know that it must be one-dimensional.

Is there anything else we can say? I'd like to work as generally as possible, and I'm willing to assume that $M$ is of finite presentation.

Comment: Why must $M$ become one-dimensional? E.g. take $M=k[x]$ a polynomial ring over $R=k$ a field, then as $k$-modules (i.e. $k$-vector spaces) $M$ and $M\otimes M$ both have countable bases, hence are isomorphic, but are certainly not one-dimensional.

Comment: they are not of finite presentation

Comment: @whoever edited the question: I appreciate the concern, but I feel that the algebraic-geometry tag is very appropriate. I phrased it in terms of modules, but this is really a problem of coherent sheaves on a scheme which can easily be reduced to the affine case. And algebraic geometers thinking geometrically might offer useful input.

Comment: Even with $M$ finitely presented and flat, this can happen with $M$ not invertible (i.e. finite locally free of rank one). Just take any ring $R$ and any $f\in R$. Then $R_f\otimes_RR_f\cong R_f\otimes_{R_f}R_f\cong R_f$ (as $R_f$-algebras even). But $R_f$ is usually isn't free over $R$, e.g., with $R=\mathbf{Z}$ and $f=N>1$. More generally, this will work with any localization of $R$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: thanks, good point. However, in your counterexample the module *is* invertible on a whole open and (zero outside?). Do you know if there's anything refined we can say? I'm thinking of something akin to the stratification according to the rank.

Comment: right, I should have said: your module is invertible once you restrict it to a whole open set.